# Не наступает событие XMLHttpRequest.onload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Не наступает событие onload, не могу понять почему?

```
<script>
...
var toremReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
toremReq.open("post", "https:xxx/barcoderequest.php", true);
toremReq.onprogress = function () {
 console.log('ONPROGRESS', toremReq.status);
 alert('ONPROGRESS');
};
toremReq.onload = function () {
 console.log('ONLOAD', toremReq.status);
 alert('ONLOAD');
};
toremReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
toremReq.send(null);
...
</script>
```

Comment: что вам консоль выдаёт? Наверняка есть какая-нибудь ошибка. Например, что кросс доменные запросы не поддерживаются

Comment: выдавала onprogress 0 и всё,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался, проблема была в том что страница слишком быстро отправляла форму другого запроса, не дождавшись ответа на этот, как только изменил с true на false:    toremReq.open("post", "https:xxx/barcoderequest.php", false);    все заработало, всем спасибо за помощь